# Vue 3 Composition API state not updating when use function

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have wasted my time for this. I am using Vue 3 options API previously and I am trying change to **compostion API**. I want to push an object to array but the **state** doesn't update value, why this happen?

```js
<script>
 
export default {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive([])

    function myFunction() {
        state.push({'item':1})
        console.log(state); // state change
    }

    watchEffect(() => {
        console.log(state) // state doesn't change
    })
        
    return {
      myFunction
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <button @click="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code. The function declaration should be as `function myFunction() { ...` instead of `function myFunction {...`

Always check the browser console for any error first before asking on internet...

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const state = Vue.reactive([])

    function myFunction() {
      state.push({
        'item': 1
      })
      console.log(state); // state change
    }

    Vue.watchEffect(() => {
      console.log(state) // state doesn't change
    })

    return {
      myFunction
    }
  }
})
app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.2.26/dist/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry but I was typo. I have update the question

Comment: @KhamadAli It is not reproducible. See (and run) my example. It works...

Comment: But when I access state outside function, it doesn't change the value

Comment: @KhamadAli As I said - what you saying is **not reproducible**. Run my code example - it works as expected